# Extracting text from an xml doc with Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an xml doc the following format

```
<samples>
   <sample count="10" intentref="none">
      Remember to
      <annotation conceptref="cf1">
         <annotation conceptref="cf2">record</annotation>
      </annotation>
      the
      <annotation conceptref="cf3">movie</annotation>
      <annotation conceptref="cf4">Taxi driver</annotation>
   </sample>
</samples>
```

and I would like to extract all the text,either the one not incapsulated in the annotation tag either the one in the annotation tag , in order to reconstruct the original phrase
So My output would be --> Remember to record the movie Taxi driver

The problem is apparently there's no way of getting the token 'the'
Here a snippet of my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
    samples = ET.fromstring("""
     <samples>
     <sample count="10" intentref="none">Remember to<annotation conceptref="cf1"><annotation conceptref="cf2">record</annotation></annotation>the<annotation conceptref="cf3">movie</annotation><annotation conceptref="cf4">Taxi driver</annotation></sample>
     </samples>
    """)

    for sample in samples.iter("sample"):
        print ('***'+sample.text+'***'+sample.tail)
        for annotation in sample.iter('annotation'):
            print(annotation.text)
            for nested_annotation in annotation.getchildren():
                  print(nested_annotation.text)
```

I thought that nested annotation would have made the trick .. but no, here's the result

```
***Remember to'***

None
record
record
movie
Taxi driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`itertext`](https://lxml.de/2.3/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itertext) method:

```
# Iterate over all the sample block
for sample in tree.xpath('//sample'):
    print(''.join(sample.itertext()))
```

---

**Full code:**

```
# Load module
import lxml.etree as etree

# Load data
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('data.xml', parser)

# Iterate over all the sample block
for sample in tree.xpath('//sample'):
    print(''.join(sample.itertext()))

# programmer l'
# enregistreur
# des
# oeuvres
# La Chevauchée de Virginia
```

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. I'd do it this way:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


samples = ET.fromstring("""<samples>
   <sample count="10" intentref="none">
      Remember to
      <annotation conceptref="cf1">
         <annotation conceptref="cf2">record</annotation>
      </annotation>
      the
      <annotation conceptref="cf3">movie</annotation>
      <annotation conceptref="cf4">Taxi driver</annotation>
   </sample>
</samples>
""")


for page in samples.findall('.//'):
    text = page.text if page.text else ''
    tail = page.tail if page.tail else ''
    print(text + tail)
```

Which is going to give you:

```
      Remember to




      the

record

movie

Taxi driver
```

You might observe that the order of the words is not the one you want but you can probably fix that by remembering the item that had both tail and text and insert the tail after that iteration. Not sure that's the correct way tough.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html = '''
<samples>
   <sample count="10" intentref="none">
      Remember to
      <annotation conceptref="cf1">
         <annotation conceptref="cf2">record</annotation>
      </annotation>
      the
      <annotation conceptref="cf3">movie</annotation>
      <annotation conceptref="cf4">Taxi driver</annotation>
   </sample>
</samples>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print(doc.selects('sample').text) # Extract all the text

# Another examples
for sample in doc.selects('sample'):
  print (sample.count, sample.annotation.text)
```

Result:

```
['Remember to record the movie Taxi driver']
10 record
```

Here are more examples. https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples